# Изменить/добавить значения в полях для разных значений другого поля postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Коллеги, есть таблица, скажем `table`, в ней есть поля:  `id` - уникальное integer, `value1, value2...valueN` - какие-то значения. Я получаю новые данные от стороннего сервиса, с помощью API запросов из Python, в которых указаны `id` и обновленные значений `value`. `id` в новых данных могут входить в множество `id` в таблице, а могут быть и новыми. Таких обновленных записей может за раз прийти тысячи. Вопрос - как мне максимально эффективно заменить те, которые присутствуют в таблице и добавить те, которые не присутствуют. Я вижу следующие варианты:

**Первый вариант**
С помощью Питона разделить множество новых `id` на те, что уже есть в таблице и те, что еще не присутствуют. И далее в два этапа:

**1 этап.** Заспамить базу апдейтами каждой отдельной записи динамически сгенерированными в цикле Python. Типа того:

```
UPDATE table
SET value2=new_value_2, value5=new_value_5
WHERE id = id_from_python;
```

Где новые значения в `SET` и каждого `id_from_python` будут подставляться питоном в цикле.

**2 этап.** Сделать `INSERT` всех новых `id` и данных для них.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, value1, value2, value3) 
VALUES (new_id, new_val, new_val, new_val), 
       (new_id, new_val, new_val, new_val);
```

**Второй вариант**

Прочитал [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763817/sql-update-fields-of-one-table-from-fields-of-another-one). Если коротко - делаем из новых данных временную таблицу и действуем как по ссылке выше, только тоже в два этапа -

**1 этап**. Меняем существующие значения в  рабочей таблице на значения из временной.

```
UPDATE table b
SET value1 = a.value1,
    value2 = a.value2,
    value3 = a.value3
FROM temp_table a
WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

**2 этап** Добавляем новые `id` из временной таблицы в рабочую.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, value1, value2, value3)  
SELECT id, value1, value2, value3
  FROM temp_table
 WHERE temp_table.id not in table.id;
```

**Гибридный вариант**
С помощью Питона разделяем `id` на новые и существующие. Из существующих `id` делаем временную таблицу и делаем `UPDATE` как во втором варианте, а множество новых `id` добавляем в рабочую таблицу как в первом варианте.

**Вопрос**.
Правильно ли составлены запросы?
Какой вариант лучше?
Есть ли варианты лучше/быстрее/оптимальнее?

Comment: *Таких обновленных записей может за раз прийти тысячи.* Настоятельно рекомендую эти новые данные слить во временную таблицу, а затем применять MERGE INTO либо INSERT .. ON CONFLICT. Основной профит - временную таблицу после наполнения ещё можно и проиндексировать, и на нагрузке и совокупном времени поиметь определённый профит. Также посмотрите на объём - возможно, есть смысл делать временную таблицу в памяти, не напрягая диск.

Comment: @Akina из соображений безопасности? Чтобы они не грохнулись в моменте?

Comment: Ещё есть неплохая альтернатива. Сериализовать данные на клиенте (например, собрать в JSON-массив), а на сервере их обратно распарсить в набор записей и использовать.

Comment: *из соображений безопасности?* В том числе. Но основной профит - от уменьшения количества запросов-ответов. В большом запросе уж или всё обработается, или всё гавкнется. А на куче мелких, с проблемой посередине... часть обработана, часть нет. Лишний геморрой. Хотя транзакции тоже никто не отменял.

Comment: @Akina благодарю за советы!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать одним запросом и пусть база данных сама выберет, вставлять данные как новые или обновлять записи. В простейшем варианте вот вам два варианта:

1. Использовать для версии 9.6+ [insert into ... on conflict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

   ```
   insert into table (id, value1, value2, value3)
   values (id, value1, value2, value3),
          (id, value1, value2, value3),
          (id, value1, value2, value3)
   on conflict (id) do update set 
       value1 = EXCLUDED.value1, 
       value2 = EXCLUDED.value2, 
       value3 = EXCLUDED.value3;
   ```
2. Использовать для версии 15+ [merge into ... when matched ... when not matched](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html)

   ```
   merge into table
   using (select id as id, value1 as value1, value2 as value2,value3 as value3) as t
   on t.id = table.id
   when matched then
       update set value1 = t.value1, 
                  value2 = t.value2, 
                  value3 = t.value3
   when not matched then
       insert (id, value1, value2, value3)
       values (t.id, t.value1, t.value2, t.value3);
   ```

Comment: Класс! Это как раз то, что я искал - запихать оба действия в один запрос! Спасибо! Но если в варианте `on conflict` мне синтаксис абсолютно понятен, то с `merge` я прошу разъяснений. Я не понимаю куда передается все множество новых значений. Догадываюсь, что куда-то в `using (select ... ) as t`, но как это должно быть синтаксически - не понимаю.

Comment: Да, и еще второй вопрос - Вы бы какой вариант предпочли? От чего зависит выбор того или иного варианта?

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov MERGE более гибкий. Но на твоей задачи эта гибкость не нужна. Так что имхо именно в твоём случае INSERT .. ON CONFLICT достаточен.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, на первой вопрос в `using (select ...) as t`, все правильно. Можно считать аналогом join основной таблицы table с тем, что отобрано внутри using. А дальше если записи нашлись по условию в on будет один или другой вариант. Какой лучше не скажу, мне привычнее merge просто потому, что с ним я работал в oracle и он более гибкий. Ну и советы Akina использовать тоже хорошо.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov *как это должно быть синтаксически - не понимаю* `.. USING ( VALUES (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) ) AS source (column1, column2) ..`

Comment: @AlexKrass прошу простить за то, что туплю, но все равно не понятно - **как именно** передать в select **множество** значений. То есть, в варианте on conflict - понятно, они передаются в VALUES последовательно через запятую, а как их во втором варианте **перечислить**? Мне синтаксис перечисления множества значений непонятен.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov то есть задача - просто преобразовать набор значений (полученный клиентом массив) в rowset в тексте запроса. Для этого используется показанным выше образом ROW constructor, а для именования полученного набора записей указываются алиасы набора и полей.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov источник  данных в select может быть любой, если надо на месте их сделать как набор строк, можно так: `USING (select * from (values (1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3)) as t (id, value1, value2, value3)) AS t`. В документации отсюда можно посмотреть примеры: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html + там внизу ссылка на VALUES страницу

Comment: @Akina правильно понимаю: `.. USING ( VALUES (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) ) AS source (column1, column2) ..` - `column1, column2` - это элиасы и я их потом использую дальше типа: `update set value1 = column1, value2=column2`?

Comment: @AlexKrass ок, спасибо! Я буду разбираться, поэксперементирую!

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Почти. Всегда используйте полное именование, включающее имя таблицы. Для исключения неоднозначностей. `update set dest.value1 = source.column1, dest.value2=source.column2`. Серверу пофиг, а порядка будет больше.

Comment: @Akina Ок, ясно! Спасибо за терпение в разъяснениях!

Comment: @AlexKrass прошу прощения, в процессе размышлений возник еще вопрос относительно `on conflict` - нет ли необходимости в установке ограничения на уникальность поля `id` (я имею ввиду UNIQUE KEY) для того, чтобы сработал `on conflict` или он сработает и без? По `merge` понятно - такого вопроса нет.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Обновление в ON CONFLICT выполняется в случае, если срабатывает ограничение уникальности (если в таблице их несколько - любое из них), а также при выполнении дополнительного условия-ограничения (если таковое имеется в запросе). Иначе выполняется вставка.

Comment: @Akina правильно ли я Вас понял: в том виде, в котором AlexKrass предложил решение, а именно: `on conflict (id)...` потребуется установка ограничения по уникальности на поле `id`. Однако, если я перепишу это выражение используя элиасы для dest и source вот так: `on conflict (source.id = dest.id)...` то мне **не надо** будет устанавливать ограничение на уникальность, обновление сработает по условию, а не по ограничению? Верно?

Comment: Нет-нет. Уникальное ограничение **обязано** быть... Сервер проверяет условие конфликта по индексу либо констрейнту - шерстить всю таблицу он не будет.

Comment: @Akina то есть, если я не хочу ставить ограничение на уникальность, то мой выбор - только merge into?

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Да, MERGE использует JOIN, который не требует наличия индекса.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150318/discussion-between-alexey-trukhanov-and-akina).